# Are there ways to do a MySql join a column of a table to another, even though they are not perfectly exactly equal strings?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have been trying to do a join between 2 tables of which i scraped on the web, but the columns of each table are not exactly the same.

Examples I can give from table 1 and table 2 are;

*GeForce 9800 GTX* and *Nvidia GeForce 9800 GTX*,
*Radeon RX 5500* and *AMD RX 5500* respectively.

I tried to use =regexreplace on google sheets to match the cases so that they are more equal, but I decided to not use it since I needed it to be more dynamic and future-proof. I tried to do a join with regexp but It does not work like how I'd imagine it to be.

```
SELECT passmark.gpuname, userbenchmark.gpuname
FROM passmark
LEFT JOIN userbenchmark 
ON passmark.gpuname=userbenchmark.gpuname
WHERE passmark.gpuname REGEXP "(RX \D+ |\S+ GTX)";
```

Are there expressions/libs/software(hopefully free) that can achieve what I would want.

Comment: I'd recommend you to create a table which stores the relation (custom name - canonical name) and use it.

Comment: That has to done in your application code.